# Add click event handler to JMenu

Tags: java, swing

I would like to catch the event when user clicks on TestSuite and add some MenuItems dynamically.

```
JMenu menu5 = new JMenu("TestSuite");
```

How to do this on Java Swing? I can catch all JMenuItem click events by adding addActionListener(this). But this time not JMenuItem, it is JMenu.

Comment: (1-) `when user clicks on TestSuite and add some MenuItems dynamically.` - This is a poor design. How do you know when the user want to "add some MenuItems" or whether they just want to display the popup menu? Maybe the first menu item should be an "Add More..." menu item.

Comment: This is a perfectly logical question.  Don't think of it as "Adding" menu items, Marcus most likely wants to create the contents of the menu dynamically whenever it is pressed based on state at the time.  His use of "Add" was probably a simplification of the problem.

Comment: @BillK, Yes I see if you are completely "rebuilding" the menu every time this is reasonable. In any case my comment was directed at the stated requirement of "adding".

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `MenuListener` to the `JMenu` and listen for the `menuSelected` event. This will allow you to dynamically add/remove menu items to the menu before the popup is made visible.

Comment: Adding a mouse listener will fail if they use accelerator keys.

Comment: @BillK You can't add accelerators to menus, I think you mean "nmenomics". In this case the MenuListener will be invoked. As I suggested you need to choose a solution based on the actual requirement. A menu is not designed to be used this way.

Comment: Lots of programs add and remove menu items based on state... Just because you haven't encountered a set of requirements you probably shouldn't assume them invalid.

Comment: That bad first part of your answer made me completely disregard the rest--Remove the mouse listener suggestion (Distracting and unlikely to be useful, in fact dead wrong for this question) and possibly mention that the event you are looking for is MenuSelected--a code sample might be good.

Answer (score -3):

you can use the ActionListener interface just like you add event on JButton.

```
menu5.addActionListener(this);
```

where "this" is the reference of the class which is implementing ActionListener interface in above sample it is the same class.

to add menu you can use menu5.add(new MenuItem("menu item1"))

Comment: (1-) You can add an ActionListener to a JMenuItem, but not to a JMenu.

Comment: `how stupid you are. go and check the java doc` - I guess I should be clearer. You can add an ActionListener to a JMenu, however the listener won't be invoked when you click on the menu. This is why the OP is asking the question. They specifically stated the ActionListener worked for the JMenuItem but not the JMenu.